# My app crashes when I try to send a request to the server

Tags: android-studio, android-intentservice

Well, it actually works pretty well on my android studio simulator but when I try to run it on my phone it just crashes. 
I just want to send a number to the server and get a response with the data that I need to that number. so this is my code which do that:

```
        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //server stuff
                try {
                    //Connecting
                    if(!userClass.equals("")) {
                        Log.i(debugString, "Attempting to connect to server");
                        socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
                        Log.i(debugString, "Connection established!");
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter((new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
                        bw.write("" + userClass);
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        input = br.readLine();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    threadComplete = true;
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    while(!threadComplete)
        continue;
```

then I just use this thread whenever I want to get the updated info for my request like that:

```
        String getUserClass = userClass;
    if(!getUserClass.equals(""))
    {
        threadComplete = false;
        userClass = getUserClass;
        thread.start();

        while (!threadComplete)
            continue;

        changes.setText(input);
    }
    else Toast.makeText(this, "Error, choose your class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

BTW, in the end of every thread (on the emulator because on my phone it crashes) I get a message:
`Skipped 91 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

and I have another problem, I also use `IntentService` to run my app service on the background, and obviously I don't want it to run constantly forever, so I made a loop which contains at the end of each loop a `wait()` command, but the problem is that when I set the time to wait for longer than 3000 milliseconds or so, the service crashes. 
my code for the background service:

```
        synchronized (this) {
        int count = 0;
        while (count<4) {

            try {
                wait(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (notifications && !userClass.equals("")) {

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //server stuff
                        try {
                            //Connecting
                            if (!userClass.equals("")) {
                                Log.i("debug", "Attempting to connect to server");
                                socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
                                Log.i("debug", "Connection established!");
                                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter((new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
                                bw.write("" + userClass);
                                bw.newLine();
                                bw.flush();

                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                                input = br.readLine();
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("debug", e.getMessage());
                        } finally {
                            complete = true;
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

                while (!complete)
                    continue;

                Toast.makeText(this, "" + input, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chanka)
                                .setContentTitle("ביטול שיעורים: ")
                                .setContentText(input);

                mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
                mNotificationId++;

                Toast.makeText(this, "" + input, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: make sure that `hostname url` is your private ip

Comment: @samir.k433 It's not the problem, the connection works and I also made the java server. The problem is that the connection works only when I'm using my pc emulator and when I try to launch it on my LG G3 it just crashes once the thread starts.
and also I get the problem : `Skipped 91 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` in log, so I think that my program is not efficient enough and it's to heavy to run for a mobile phone, and I just don't know how to make it work and more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following piece of code is the culprit -

```
while (!threadComplete)
   continue;
```

You are kind of putting the main thread on a long loop. Android does not allow that. The general construct in these kind of use cases is this -

> Step 1 -  Show a progress dialog to the user indicating that you are
>   doing something important and user needs to wait till that is
>   complete. Show some meaningful text in the progress dialog which makes
>   sense to the user.
>
> Step 2 - Start a async connection to the server. There are lot of
>   options in Android to do this. But for your purpose `AsyncTask` might
>   be useful. Connect to your server, fetch and parse data in the
>   `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` and once the task is complete,
>   let `onPostExecute` publish the same to the Main thread.
>
> Step 3 - Once you get back the result from the Async task, you may
>   dismiss the progress dialog and continue with whatever you were doing.

Please note that the main thread should not be blocked at any time. This is the event handling thread of the app and handles all events (User initiated or system initiated). If the thread is blocked, you get the kind of error you are seeing now. Specifically in your case, Android system is not able to do some draw operations because of the while loop.

Comment: Well it worked great, but I still have that problem that my service stops if I set the delay between each check for more than 10 seconds. This is my code for the service:
`protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        synchronized (this) {
            new StartChecking().start((long) 7000);
        }

    }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Asynctask and run the socket establisment codes inside it :)

```
     socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
```